# Нужна ли запятая перед приложением?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, приложение, придаточное-предложение

> Вы впустую тратите время, которое вы могли потратить на реально
> полезное дело(,) — организацию встречи.

Нужно ли закрывать запятой придаточную часть или приложение тоже будет в нее входить?

Comment: Вы впустую тратите время на организацию встречи, а могли бы потратить его на что-то по-настоящему полезное.
Вы впустую тратите время(которое вы могли бы потратить на что-то полезное) на организацию встречи.

Comment: @Буратино Контекст нельзя изменять!

Comment: У меня сомнения в грамотном согласовании фразы, расстановкой знаков препинания тут дело не исправить. Потому что тут предложение распадается на две конфликтующих фразы, одна из которых разбивает на части другую, причем на месте согласования через тире. Можно одну заключить в скобки, в скобках не важно что пишут, это дополнительная информация.

Comment: @Буратино Фраза корректна. Не сомневайтесь.

Comment: Ну вот смотрите. Херим "на реально полезное дело" - так как штамп-урод, заменяем его словами "на дело" или "с пользой". Получаем: Вы впустую тратите время, которое вы могли потратить на дело / потратить с пользой... А теперь еще придаточное к придаточному, зачем? ну ладно делаем так. Вы в пустую тратите время, которое могли бы потратить на дело (чего?) организации встречи(знаки не нужны)/ с пользой: организовать встречу / на дело(а именно): на организацию встречи. Такие варианты и только с предлогом, без предлога и с тире, это согласование через опу.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая не нужна.
Определяемое слово и его приложение не могут находиться в разных предложениях.
***...Дело – организацию...*** – цельная структура, она входит в состав придаточного предложения.