# Запятая не стыке сочинительного союза и союзного слова

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, союзы, и

Позиция вроде бы одна и та же, но запятые то ставятся, то нет. Можно объяснить?

> *Мои весьма обыкновенные лошади не могли доставить мне этого «высокого»
> наслаждения, **и,** как бы я ни разваливался в моей старой коляске, никто
> не обратил бы на нее внимания, и потому я решился при первом удобном
> случае свернуть в рощу и отправиться гулять пешком.*
>
> *Заподозрив меня в вольномыслии, тем более вредном, что я его старался
> ничем не обнаруживать, он то и дело вызывал меня «по катехизису», **и**
> как бы я ни отвечал, не ставил мне больше тройки...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во втором предложении не туда поставили запятую.
Союз ***и*** соединяет однородные сказуемые: *он вызывал и не ставил*.

*Заподозрив меня в вольномыслии, тем более вредном, что я его старался ничем не обнаруживать, он то и дело вызывал меня «по катехизису» **и,** как бы я ни отвечал, не ставил мне больше тройки...*

Comment: А в первом правильно стоит? Я бы не ставила там. Это примеры из корпуса.

Comment: В первом правильно. Там запятая перед "и" разделяет простые предложения в составе сложного. // В Нацкорпусе собрано много чего, с ошибками в том числе.

Comment: Я о запятой после "и".

Comment: После тоже. *"как бы я ни разваливался в моей старой коляске", "как бы я ни отвечал"* – обособляются с обеих сторон.

Comment: А разве тут не та же ситуация, что в примере Розенталя? Он давно уже уехал, и где он теперь, никто не знает — союз и присоединяет целое сложноподчиненное предложение.

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна Скажите, пожалуйста, а что Вас не устроило в [этом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475041/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-приложением/475051#475051) моём ответе?

Comment: Можно и так трактовать, но запятая точно не ошибка. А вот во втором предложении перед "и" она лишняя.

Comment: Интересовали знаки именно на стыке союзов (1-й пример), у Розенталя просто этот пример выделяется, а в литературе пишут по-разному (с запятой между союзами и без нее).

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна Ну, Розенталь тоже собирал примеры из литературы, привёл один-два в этой теме для разнообразия :). А по общему правилу запятая ставится (если после придаточного нет второй части составного союза). // Так что насчёт прошлого ответа?

Answer (score 1):

Я поддерживаю **ответ Александра:**

1. **Однородные члены**:  " .*..он то и дело **вызывал** меня «по катехизису» и, как бы я ни отвечал, **не ставил** мне больше тройки...".*

**[Розенталь, 4(2)](http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_36.htm#ppp_5)**

**Однородные члены:** *По-видимому, своим словам **придавал** он не малое значение и, чтобы усугубить им цену, **старался** произносить их врастяжку* (Ч.);

2. Я бы не стала изучать правила **по этому источнику**:  "Записки социалиста-революционера...".  Тогда не было строгих норм, знаки ставили по смыслу, по произношению, да еще редакторы могли подправить.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon, а то я уже расстроился... :)